# cakephp disabling pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I need to disable pagination on cakephp 2

I get a list of elements by using PDO queries without cake find methods.

and set the result as
    $this->set('elements', $elements);

if I dont use $this->paginate();
I just can view the "view" as plain text, without the layout; something like:

id  name    Actions
1   jhon    Delete
2   Pep     Delete

but without any css. And viewing page source

```
&lt;div class="index"&gt;
    &lt;table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    &lt;tr>
    &lt;th>id&lt;/th> [...]
```

Means that begins on the view template, but without layout. I put a beforeFilter function calling the 'default' layout i use:

```
function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
   $this->layout = 'default';
}
```

but nothing happens.
If I put $this->paginate(), the the layout is rendered, but I don't make unnecessary queries.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear, and/or you're leaving something vital out.  You wouldn't "disable" pagination - you would just not use it.

Comment: Disabling pagination ?? Simply dont do coding for pagination . Simple :) :)

Comment: I use an own FindAll pdo method to get records.

if I dont put This>Paginate(); I get all but is not rendering the layout. source code begins on <div class="index"> instead on HTML tag, It means that I'm getting only the view without layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want pagination then simply update your view by removing the pagination code and simply use find('all');

You can follow the CakePHP official site document to make the concept clear.

[CakePHP Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html)

Answer (score -1):

I use an own FindAll pdo method to get records.

if I dont put This>Paginate();
I get all but is not rendering the layout.
source code begins on <div class="index"> instead on HTML tag, It means tha I get only the view without layout.